# OPC UA .Net Client Stack for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, opc, opc-ua

Looking at the following open source CLient SDK that can be used in Xamarin. [UA.NetLibrary](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandardLibrary)

The problem is that not sure on how to build it. Any ideas? I can't open it either.

Then is there any SDKs that I can use for my Xamarin.Android project that is an OPC UA Client?

Comment: You should first build the UA.Net Library. It will output a couple of assemblies that you can then reference from your Xamarin project. I'm not sure you will be able to run the application from an Android device but it is definitely an interesting approach.

Comment: i was able to build it and reference it in Xamarin.Forms. The problem is that i wasn't able to connect to an OPC UA Server. Will try again and update this thread